# Create a result for a line chart with dates

Tags: sqlite

I have this table in SQLite which I use to record the risk level identified in vulnerability assesments according to the day the scan was performed. 
This table looks like this:

```
Scan Date  | Risk
2014-04-20 | 26  
2014-04-24 |  60  
2014-04-26 | 156  
2014-04-28 |  26
```

What I want to do is  to build a table like the following in order to use it to display the results on a line graph day by day (including those days without scanning, where the risk level is the same as the last scanning):

```
  Date    | Risk 
2014-04-20|  26  
2014-04-21|  26  
2014-04-22|  26  
2014-04-23|  26  
2014-04-24|  60  
2014-04-25|  60  
2014-04-26| 156  
2014-04-27| 156  
2014-04-28|  26
```

How can I do it using SQL?

Comment: This can be done in SQL - but why? Can't the graphing application complete the gaps?

Comment: The risk on 2/21 is not 26. Instead it is unknown. Therefore you should not plot a 26 either. Just plot the dates that the measurements were taken on and leave gaps for the other days.

Comment: ypercube - > I have to resolve it at SQL level if is it possible.

Comment: Sebastian Meine - > It's company policy, not mine. What I have to do is to put it as they want in a query

Comment: This is possible, but how do you know which dates to include in the output table?

Comment: CL -> Those dates between the first date and the last date. For the example I posted dates between 2014-04-20 and 2014-04-28. There was an error in the example, the month is always April (4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use a recursive [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to generate the missing dates:

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_dates(d) AS
 (VALUES ('2014-04-20')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(d, '+1 day')
  FROM all_dates
  WHERE d < '2014-05-28')
SELECT ...
```

Instead of using constants, these values can be read directly from the table.
To look up the latest matching risk value, we can use a subquery:

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_dates(d) AS
 (SELECT min(ScanDate) FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(d, '+1 day')
  FROM all_dates
  WHERE d < (SELECT max(ScanDate) FROM MyTable))
SELECT d AS Date,
       (SELECT Risk
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE ScanDate <= d
        ORDER BY ScanDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS Risk
FROM all_dates
```

Comment: CL and Jchao thanks for your help.  both approaches were useful

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but if you have a calendar table (there are plenty of scripts online to create one), you can run the following. I joined calendar to your table and replaced the NULL's (which in your case would not have a scan date) with the last risk number.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/626ee/3)

```
select caldate, scandate,
(select risk from yourTable where scandate = (select max(scandate) from yourTable where 
  scandate is not null and scandate <= caldate)) 
from calendar a
left join yourTable b on a.caldate = b.ScanDate
where caldate between '2014-04-20' and '2014-04-28'
```